# How could I create a class that can give me C4251 warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When we compile codes in VC, we somethings have the C4251 warnings. In my case, most of the warnings come from the fact that STL is a member of the `_declspec(dllexport)` class. In order to have a deep understanding of the warning, I plan to create a class that will intrigue the warning. I have tried the following cases, but no C4251 warning is given, and I was wondering whether a simple example can be given. Thanks!

The cases I have tried:

```
class _declspec(dllexport) ClassTest
{
public:
      ExportClass<int> myexport;
     ClassUse myuse;
     int i;
};
```

Case 1:

```
template <typename T>
class  ExportClass
{
public:
    T a;
    T b;
};
```

Case 2:

```
class   ClassUse
{
public:
    int counts;
    float f_value;
    std::vector<int> abc;
    void get_func();

    template <typename T>
    T ouput_value()
    {

        return static_cast<T>(3);
    };

        template<class T>
        int connected()
        {
            T abc;
            return 3;
        }

};
```

**EDIT:**

I want to make it clear that the warning will not comes from invoking STL.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) gives an example of a class that gives the warning message.

See following example if you want to generate the warning message without making use of STL:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    CString m_str; // WARNING C4251 HERE
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to create a class that generates the warning without any link to STL. Sorry, I did not make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w.aspx) in that particular case:

> Compiler Warning (level 1) C4251
>   'identifier' : class 'type' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'type2'

this can happen when

```
// C4251.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc /MTd /W2 /c
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Node;
class __declspec(dllimport) VecWrapper : vector<Node *> {};   // C4251
```